# Roll Back Migration Error Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have updated staging database with the migrations already  applied on local db. But some of the migrations did not make changes to the database although update-database procedure went smoothly and said the changes were applied.

I have put the output in this [file](https://ufile.io/711179jn)

Although the output clearly says that changes were applied, when i check the database both ExportCSV and ExportCSV2 clearly missing the fields M9, M10 A4-A20, some fields as TI1 or I1 are added but some remained.

I tried to rollback to the last good migration  error and wanted to run add-migration on the staging database but i got this

```
    Error Number:257,State:3,Class:16
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

For a start i would be good if i could rollback the database.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to grant permissions to see your shared file. As is, I can not review it.

Comment: Might be in your script you  convert int field value to datetime because of that you faced this issue. like ISNULL(IntField, GETDATE()) or CAST(IntField to datetime) etc.

Comment: @LaughingVergil Vergil Sorry didn't noticed that only my company can share docs. Changed the link you can see it now.

Comment: @NP007 Actually the in the database is date time, and when i rollback migrations trying to convert it to int. Up method `AlterColumn("dbo.ExportCSV", "P1FanContacted", c => c.DateTime());
            AlterColumn("dbo.ExportCSV", "P2FanContacted", c => c.DateTime());
            AlterColumn("dbo.ExportCSV", "P3FanContacted", c => c.DateTime()); ` Down method `AlterColumn("dbo.ExportCSV", "P3FanContacted", c => c.Int());
            AlterColumn("dbo.ExportCSV", "P2FanContacted", c => c.Int());
            AlterColumn("dbo.ExportCSV", "P1FanContacted", c => c.Int()); `

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem following this procedure.

Commented the models in dbcontext, Dropped the two problematic tables by code-first approach(add- migration than update-database).

Uncommented the tables, recreated them by add- migration than update-database.

Maybe better approach is when updating the staging or live database instead of running the migrations first to create migration from model.